# number keys wont function

Tags: keyboard

Acer aspire one model kav60 , with windows xp ,number lock key functions (light turns on and off) but it wont type numbers. I have tried factory restore, reinstalling driver and using on screen keyboard. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04

- Click on the System Menu -> System Settings -> Universal Access -> Point and Clicking
- Turn "Mouse Keys" off

Comment: Thanks, checked mouse key, but this is turned offf

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be the problem, it is probably a driver issue or similar, as this is not enabled by default.

Open system settings, and click Universal Access

[image]

Click pointing and Clicking.

[image]

Finally, click the slider to turn it off.

[image]